# Почему атаки Pass-the-Hash до сих пор работают?

Tags: windows, безопасность, windows-8, ntlm, kerberos

По умолчанию в Windows Server 2003 и выше для аутентификации в домене используется пакет Kerberos. Однако есть утилиты (например, Windows Credentials Editor), которые позволяют провести атаку Pass-the-Hash даже в Windows 8, и при этом они работают с хранилищами хэшей в памяти lsass.exe, относящимися к пакету NTLM аутентификации.
  Так почему атака проходит, если должен использоваться Kerberos? У клиента есть возможность инициировать аутентификацию по протоколу NTLM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот выставили вы почтовый сервер в интернет, как в таком случае будет работать Kerberos? Выставлять ещё и контроллер домена наружу? Во избежание этого используется NTLM.

Кстати, Windows Credentials Editor и подобные требуют прав локального администратора?

Comment: Да, WCE требует. Остальные скорее всего тоже.

Comment: Я нашел презентацию "Still passing the hash 15 years later". Так вот там написано, что для Kerberos нужно, чтобы клиент/сервер были в домене, а если кто-то из них не в домене, то используется NTLM. Ни на msdn, ни где-то еще об этом по-моему не писали. Может я пропустил что-то?

Comment: Основное отличие Kerberos в том, что клиент аутентифицируется на контроллере домена, получает от него билет и дальше этот билет показывает стороннему серверу. Соответственно, если в интернет торчит только сторонний сервер, то клиенту негде получить билет Kerberos и тогда используется NTLM. По этой причине по-умолчанию возможность NTLM-авторизации включена.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!